# trying to redirect a link on prestashop. link gets biased depending on language setting

Tags: php, prestashop

http://www.klumklum.com/es/autenticacion?back=category.php%3Fid_category%3D136

versus

http://www.klumklum.com/es/pagina-no-encuentra

I used this `public/override/controllers/CategoryController.php` code:

```
<?php class CategoryController extends CategoryControllerCore
{
    public function displayContent() {
      if(!$this->category->checkAccess((int)(self::$cookie->id_customer))) {
          if(!self::$cookie->isLogged())       
            Tools::redirectLink('authentification?back=category.php?id_category='.$this->category->id); 
          else
            parent::displayContent();

        } else
          self::$smarty->display(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'category.tpl');
     }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? I noticed that you missed some `{` and `}` in your `if / else` statements.

Comment: @bish where should they go?

Comment: seems to work! thanks!

Comment: was my comment the solution for your problem?